# Angular 4, Immutability, and Class Properties

Tags: angular, functional-programming, immutability

As I attempted to implement more functional programming patterns in an Angular 4 app, I hit a wall. A service I was using to fetch some JSON would return, get mapped over, and then the result would be set to a set of class properties, which would be accessed from the component's HTML.

However, because of scope, there was no way to have both immutability and class properties accessible from HTML. I suspect this is a [limitation of Angular's design](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/the-rise-of-functional-programming-and-the-death-of-angularjs), but wanted to confirm with those that have more experience with both Angular and functional programming.

The code I've provided is where I'm at. The properties on the class cannot be modified in order to maintain immutability, but without them, the HTML template cannot be populated either.

```js
export class BuildstampBannerComponent implements OnInit {
  buildstampTime;
  commitHash;
  commitAuthor;
  commitTime;
  commitMessage;
  commitTag;

  public prepCommitData = (commitData): =>
    Object.assign({}, ...commitData, {
      commitTime: commitData.time,
      commitMessage: commitData.message,
      commitHash: commitData.hash,
      commitAuthor: commitData.author,
      commitBranch: commitData.branch,
      commitStatus: commitData.status,
      commitTag: commitData.tag,
    });

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private router: Router,
    private buildstampService: BuildstampService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildstampService.getBuildstampData().subscribe(commit => {
      prepCommitData(commit[0]);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="github-data">
    <h2>GitHub</h2>
    <dl id="latest-commit-data"> 
      <dt>Commit hash:</dt> 
      <dd><a href="{{ commitHash }}"><data id="git-commit_hash">{{ commitHash }}</data></a></dd>
      
      <dt>Commit message:</dt> 
      <dd id="git-commit_message"><a href="{{ commitHash }}">{{ commitMessage }}</a></dd>
      
      <dt>Commit time:</dt>
      <dd><time id="git-commit_time">{{ commitTime }}</time></dd>
      
      <dt>Commit author:</dt>
      <dd id="git-commit_author">{{ commitAuthor }}</dd>

      <dt>Status:</dt> 
      <dd id="git-branch_status">{{ commitStatus }}</dd>
    
      <dt>Tag:</dt> 
      <dd><data id="git-tag">{{ commitTag }}</data></dd>
    </dl>
  </section>
```

Comment: I don't think the template display properties need to be immutable, but what you could do is have an object that contains the properties instead. Then, update this object each time, `this.properties = prepCommitData(commit[0])` and use `propties.<propname>` in your template.

Comment: Thanks @Explosion Pills. Unfortunately, that’s what I had before. I am interested in what you said about template properties though. I suppose it could be a bit like the classic Rich Hickey question: “If a pure function mutates some local data in order to produce an immutable return value, is that ok?” https://clojure.org/reference/transients

Comment: I didn't comment;  I only changed the tag from [tag:angularjs] to [tag:angular].  I think you wanted to ask @ExplosionPills about their comment.

Comment: Thanks. Updated to reflect.